# simplify A'B'C'+A'B'C+A'BC'+A'BC+ABC into minimal 1st canonical form

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

Is there anyone who can advise me?
I cannot seem to simplify this function into minimal 1st canonical form using boolean algebra. 
[image]

With my first attempt I obtained: 
[image]
With my second attempt I obtained:
[image]

I used the K-Map loop technique and I got:[image]

The correct answer I obtained from the online Logic circuit simplification solver also gave the answer:[image]

Can someone please point out the mistakes I have made in my 1st and 2nd attempts using Boolean algebra method?

Also can you please let me know the reason why I did not obtain the minimal 1st canonical form directly from the K-Map loops and needed to further simplify the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the 2nd part of your question: K-map representations connect from top to bottom, and left edge to right edge- so the outer 4 corners are all part of one adjacency group, A' (This means you can derive A' + BC directly)

Comment: Thank you, for pointing that out. Also can you tell me what mistakes I've made in the 2 methods?

Comment: How did you get 1 in the second step? I am assuming you did -
(A'B' + AB)C and then put A'B' + AB equal to 1.

Well,  if that is the case then this is where you made the mistake. A'B' + AB is not equal to 1. Try putting A = 1 and B = 0, it won't satisfy. Plus if you get 1 in the Boolean equation then the entire result has to be 1.